# How can I find a particular named file within a particular named directory that could be anywhere in file system?

Tags: find, xargs

I am trying to find a file within a directory where both the name of the file and the name of the directory are known. For example, say I want to find

"`...don't know this part of file path stem).../dirname/filename.extension`"

I have a feeling I am looking for something like this:

```
find / -type d -name "dirname" | xargs find * -type f -name "filename.extension"
```

But I can't seem to hit upon the right combo. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for the `-path` option:

```
find / -path "*/dirname/filename.extension"
```

The problem in your command is the joker `*` after the pipe `|` expends to the list of files in the current directory so the `find` command will search inside them. Another way would be using the `-exec` option, `{}` will be replaced by what the first find finds (but, just why do things this way?):

```
find / -type d -name "dirname" -exec find {} -type f -name "filename.extension" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-wholename` instead of `-name`. It will let you search the full path name.

```
find / -wholename "*directory/filename" -print
```